# Does showing livestream-lesson viewers stats about other viewers increase engagement?

Tags: user-engagement, education

Consider a livestreaming platform for teaching (various age groups).

Viewers cannot interact with other viewers, but they can interact with teaching assistants.

Would showing key statistics about the engagement of other viewers lead to a positive individual increase in engagement and motivation?

I'm aware it is generally encouraging in other contexts, such as YouTube livestreams. However, this is a case where people are logging in to specifically to learn.

Is there any research into this?

Comment: I'm willing to do the legwork of reading the source material, of course. Though brief summaries would be helpful and appreciated. I'm not entirely sure what to search for or where to get the best knowledge on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the right answer only by conducting user research and domain research.

### Domain research

It's simple. If all of your competitors have a feature, you'll need it too. Because for the user, the lack of a feature can be critical to the non-use of your product.

### User research

User research should aim to find out the user's reaction and willingness to use a feature. I would recommend using the Kano model because it's the simplest way to do this job properly.

More about Kano:

1. [Kano Model (Part 1): Understanding the Kano Model](https://brianrhea.com/what-to-build-kano-model/)
2. [Kano Model (Part 2): Creating Your Survey](https://brianrhea.com/create-survey-kano-model/)
3. [Kano Model Template](https://miro.com/templates/kano-model/)

And if the user research shows that the feature is needed, don't forget to evaluate the business value and its relative complexity to implement:
[Using Prioritization Matrices to Inform UX Decisions](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/prioritization-matrices/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer – there's some helpful stuff there. I had planned to suggest we do some split testing in the event there isn't much existing research on it. One thing, though – I'm not sure a survey is the right answer here. I don't think this is the kind of thing where typical people would be able to answer this question usefully, since it would require that they have actually experienced both and had time to reflect on their emotions about it. It's entirely possible the effect is unconscious for many, too – its mere presence, just barely registered, may have an effect.

Comment: Though, I think some split testing would be duly prudent, anyway. However, existing research would be useful to help me understand the details of which statistics and how they presented are be most effective.